# truncating a text file does not change the file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, python-3.x, truncation

When a novice (like me) asks for reading/processing a text file in python he often gets answers like:

```
with open("input.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #do your stuff
```

Now I would like to truncate everything in the file I'm reading after a special line. After modifying the example above I use:

```
with open("input.txt", 'r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line.rstrip("\n\r") #for debug
        if line.rstrip("\n\r")=="CC":
           print "truncating!"  #for debug
           file.truncate();
           break;
```

and expect it to throw away everything after the first "CC" seen. Running this code on input.txt:

```
AA
CC
DD
```

the following is printed on the console (as expected):

```
AA
CC
truncating!
```

but the file "input.txt" stays unchanged!?!?

How can that be? What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** After the operation I want the file to contain:

```
AA
CC
```

Comment: You are truncating from the end of the file so you need to seek to the correct position in the file so something like `file.seek(0); file.truncate()`

Comment: @SirParselot I want to truncate the file after "CC", after `file.seek(0)` the whole information would be gone!

Comment: That's why I said something like. You'll need to find the point in the file right after CC and seek to there

Comment: @SirParselot Maybe my expectations are wrong, but I expect to move the current position with every read of a line and truncate the file after having read "CC" (because then the current position becomes the "right" position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to glibdud's answer, truncate() needs the size from where it deletes the content. You can get the current position in your file by the `tell()`  command. As he mentioned, by using the for-loop, the `next()` prohibits commands like tell. But in the suggested while-loop, you can truncate at the current tell()-position. So the complete code would look like this:

Python 3:

```
with open("test.txt", 'r+') as file:
line = file.readline()
while line:
    print(line.strip())
    if line.strip() == "CC":
        print("truncating")
        file.truncate(file.tell())
        break
    line = file.readline()
```

Comment: `truncate` defaults to the current position, so the `tell` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I thought so, but in my script, it didn't work and deleted nothing. Giving it any position, it truncated right after that.

Comment: That's odd, it worked fine without the `tell` in my testing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm in Python 3. In Python 2 it worked without tell as expected. Seems to make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduce that. Not sure what to make of it... seems like it must be a bug, given that the Python 3 documentation still indicates that it should default to the current position.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this problem out. I can reproduce it as well. Firstly I thought that maybe python3.4 doing an internal buffering and just gets confused somehow, but my test with python3 showed nothing of the kind: `for line in file` is twice as fast as `while loop` for my test cases. The same holds for python2: the is a factor 2 between two method, but the slower python2 method is as fast as the faster python3 method...

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're falling victim to a read-ahead buffer used internally by Python. From the [documentation for the file.next() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects):

> A file object is its own iterator, for example `iter(f)` returns f (unless f is closed). When a file is used as an iterator, typically in a `for` loop (for example, `for line in f: print line.strip()`), the `next()` method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises `StopIteration` when EOF is hit when the file is open for reading (behavior is undefined when the file is open for writing). In order to make a `for` loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()` with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right. However, using `seek()` to reposition the file to an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer.

The upshot is that the file's position is not where you would expect it to be when you truncate. One way around this is to use [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) to loop over the file, rather than the iterator:

```
line = file.readline()
while line:
    ...
    line = file.readline()
```