# Python file read and write

Tags: python, file

I have file with scores:

```
Foo 12
Bar 44
```

I try to sort it, erase it and than write sorted scores into it.
But I get error:

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Here is my function:

```
def Sort():
scores = []
with open("results.txt") as x:
    for linia in x:
        name,score=linia.split(' ')
        score=int(score)
        scores.append((name,score))
    scores.sort(key=lambda sc: sc[1])
x.truncate()
for name, score in scores:
    x.write(name+' '+str(score))
```

Comment: Might want to read how open() works. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open - also what SirParselot says.

Comment: Your second for loop, which has a call a write call in it, is outside the with statement which closes the file once you jump out of it

Comment: You are trying to write to file after opening it in the read mode.

Comment: Has it been edited since?  Both `for` loops appear inside the `with` statement block (but the file is opened as `r+`).

Comment: @bartekshadowm post the code as it is when you get the error, right now you would not get any error related to the file being closed.

Comment: Yes but still I cant erase my file. It just adds sorted values into file.

Comment: @bartekshadow, `f.truncate(f.seek(0))`, open with `r+`, indent the for loop inside the with block and it will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file remains open only **inside** the `with` block. After that, Python will automatically close it. You need to open it a second time, using a second `with` block.

```
def Sort():
    scores = []
    with open("results.txt") as x:
        # x is open only inside this block!
        for linia in x:
            name, score=linia.split(' ')
            score = int(score)
            scores.append((name, score))
        scores.sort(key=lambda sc: sc[1])

    with open("results.txt", "w") as x:
        # open it a second time, this time with `w`
        for name, score in scores:
            x.write(name + ' ' + str(score))

Sort()
```

---

This can also be done using just a single file open. In this case, you open the file in a dual read/write mode (r+) and use `truncate` to erase the previous file contents.

```
def Sort():
    scores = []
    with open("results.txt", "r+") as x:
        for linia in x:
            name, score = linia.split(' ')
            score = int(score)
            scores.append((name, score))
        scores.sort(key=lambda sc: sc[1])

        # Go to beginning of file
        x.seek(0)

        # http://devdocs.io/python~3.5/library/io#io.IOBase.truncate
        # If no position is specified to truncate, 
        # then it resizes to current position

        x.truncate()
        # note that x.truncate(0) does **not** work,
        # without an accompanying call to `seek`.
        # a number of control characters are inserted
        # for reasons unknown to me.

        for name, score in scores:
            x.write(name + ' ' + str(score) + '\n')
```

However, personally, I feel that the first approach is better, and you’re less likely to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: No you don't have to open twice, you can use r+ with truncate as the OP is doing in their own code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, this is a simple solution (not to mention correct). No need for `truncate` or `r+`. Maybe someone else will find it useful.

Comment: You said you need to open it twice, you don't so that is misinformation, the only thing wrong in the OP's code is indentation

Comment: @PadraicCunningham err no, OP has to seek to 0 before he can call `truncate`.

Comment: Beware that in Python 3, [strange things can happen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34884040/789671) when you mix read and write mode operations on text-mode files.

Comment: @glibdud "I feel that the first approach is better, and you’re less likely to shoot yourself in the foot.”.