# Python's file.truncate() unexpectedly does not truncate

Tags: python

I have this very simple Python program:

```
def print_file(filename):    
    with open(filename,'r') as read_file:
        print(read_file.read())

def create_random_file(filename,count):
    with open(filename,'w+', encoding='utf-8') as writefile:
        for row_num in range(count):
            writefile.write(f'{row_num}: fo bar baz\n')

def truncate_file_after_first_line(file,read_a_line):
    file.seek(0,0)  # go to start of file
    print(f"After seeking to 0, at position {file.tell()}");
    if (read_a_line):
        header = file.readline()
        print(f"After reading a line, at position {file.tell()}");
        print(f"Found header '{header.rstrip()}'\n")
    file.write('TRUNCATE AFTER THIS\n')
    print(f"After writing marker, at position {file.tell()}");
    file.truncate()

def mangle_file(filename,read_a_line):
    with open(filename,'r+') as file:
        truncate_file_after_first_line(file,read_a_line)

# ----

filename = 'testpy.txt'
read_a_line = True

create_random_file(filename,5)
print("Original file:")
print_file(filename)
mangle_file(filename,read_a_line)
print("Truncated file:")
print_file(filename)
```

So, I:

- I create a file with 5 lines (and print it to stdout too).
- Then, in `mangle_file()`:

  - I open the file with [the `r+` option](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/), i.e. *Open for reading and writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.*
  - Depending on bool `read_a_line`, I then either

    - a) Seek to position 0, **read a line**, write the marker `TRUNCATE AFTER THIS\n`, then truncate the file.
    - b) Seek to position 0, write the marker `TRUNCATE AFTER THIS\n`, then truncate the file.
  - Finally I close the file
- And then re-read it to print it.

Sounds straightforward but for a) where the first line in the file (i.e. `0: fo bar baz`) is read before truncation, the resulting file is:

```
0: fo bar baz
1: fo bar baz
2: fo bar baz
3: fo bar baz
4: fo bar baz
TRUNCATE AFTER THIS
```

i.e. **the `truncate()` did nothing**, the marker has been appened to the untruncated file. Whereas I would expect truncation after the first line read:

```
0: fo bar baz
TRUNCATE AFTER THIS
```

For b), as expected, the resulting file is

```
TRUNCATE AFTER THIS
```

What do I get wrong about `truncate()`?

**Update: Added some `tells`**

With `read_a_line = True`

```
Original file:
0: fo bar baz
1: fo bar baz
2: fo bar baz
3: fo bar baz
4: fo bar baz

After seeking to 0, at position 0
After reading a line, at position 14
Found header '0: fo bar baz'

After writing marker, at position 90

Truncated file:
0: fo bar baz
1: fo bar baz
2: fo bar baz
3: fo bar baz
4: fo bar baz
TRUNCATE AFTER THIS
```

With `read_a_line = False`

```
Original file:
0: fo bar baz
1: fo bar baz
2: fo bar baz
3: fo bar baz
4: fo bar baz

After seeking to 0, at position 0
After writing marker, at position 20
Truncated file:
TRUNCATE AFTER THIS
```

Comment: Unless `file.readline()` actually does not read a line but somehow the whole file? 

Comment: This is pretty old but appears to be exact same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879318/why-isnt-truncate-defaulting-properly-to-the-current-position-for-files

Comment: @defaultUsernameN Good catch, going through the links, an [open problem from 2016](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70346) that is still open  Just my luck.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Exactly, `readline` *returns* a single line, but internal buffering means it may have (and did) read more than just one line in order to do so.

Comment: (Confusingly, IIRC, reading uses a pointer into the in-memory buffer, but writing uses a pointer to the disk. Careful reading of the `io` module's documentation will help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fopen documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html):

> Reads and writes may be intermixed on read/write streams in any
> order.  Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning
> function intervene between output and input, unless an input
> operation encounters end-of-file.  (If this condition is not met,
> then a read is allowed to return the result of writes other than
> the most recent.)  Therefore it is good practice (and indeed
> sometimes necessary under Linux) to put an fseek(3) or fsetpos(3)
> operation between write and read operations on such a stream.
> This operation may be an apparent no-op (as in fseek(..., 0L,
> SEEK_CUR) called for its synchronizing side effect).

If you change

```
    file.write('TRUNCATE AFTER THIS\n')
```

to

```
    file.seek(file.tell()) 
    file.write('TRUNCATE AFTER THIS\n')
```

the function should behave as you intended (it does on my MacOS). Otherwise, "r+" may behave as if the mode was like "ra" (even though that is not a valid mode) -- that is, only appending later in the file or at the very end (depending on how much text was already buffered).

Comment: It's not necessarily going to append to the very end without the seek.  It's just that the file is buffered and did a block read of more than just the first line internally, but only *returned* the first line.  Write 1000 lines (or more) instead.  I got the truncation in the middle of line 488.

Comment: Ah, thanks for correcting that. I was not aware if that. Makes sense - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`truncate()` does truncate but it is at the wrong position. As discussed in the thread linked by @defaultUsernameN, there seems to be some undocumented behaviour in the interaction between `readline()` and `truncate()` regarding which position they regard as the current position in the file. The corresponding [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70346) is still open.

In your code, you can fix this by manually seeking again before truncating:

```py
def truncate_file_after_first_line(file,read_a_line):
    file.seek(0,0)  # go to start of file
    if (read_a_line):
        header = file.readline()
        print(f"Found header '{header.rstrip()}'\n")
        file.seek(0,1) # go to second line
    file.write('TRUNCATE AFTER THIS\n')
    file.truncate()
```

Output:

```
Original file:
0: fo bar baz
1: fo bar baz
2: fo bar baz
3: fo bar baz
4: fo bar baz

Found header '0: fo bar baz'

Truncated file:
0: fo bar baz
TRUNCATE AFTER THIS
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - this open issue is already 8 yrs old...
Btw, it's not just the truncate that happens at the wrong position, but also the write, after the initial read.