# Python file I/O file.seek() vs file.read() pointer behavior

Tags: python

I ran across an issue where I didn't get the expected output based on my understanding.

The difference between the two code snippets is file.seek(3,0) vs file.read(3).

in both cases I verified that the file pointer is at position 3, however when I write to the file I get different results. Can someone explain why this is?

```
#=====Code Snippet #1===========

# original file has "hi world!"
with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
    file.seek(3,0) # we move the file pointer to index 3
    print(file.tell()) # prints 3
    file.write("friend!")
# file now has "hi friend!"  <--- AS EXPECTED


# ======Code Snippet #2===========

# original file has "hi world!"
with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
    file.read(3) # We read characters at index 0,1,2 and move the file pointer to index 3
    print(file.tell()) # prints 3
    file.write("friend!")
# file now has "hi world!friend!" <--- NOT AS EXPECTED
# =====================================
```

Comment: Seeking to arbitrary integers in text mode is undefined behavior, by the way. You're only supposed to seek to offsets given to you by `tell`.

Comment: Interesting finding. Do you see the same behavior when setting `buffering=0` in the open call?

Comment: I remember something about needing to `seek` to the current file position to synchronize the buffering when switching between writing and reading, but I don't remember where this was documented.

Comment: @user2357112 While technically true, if they're on Linux there's no difference between text and binary mode.

Comment: I reproduced this on my Mac.

Comment: @user2357112 You should post that as an answer. Putting `file.seek(file.tell())` before `file.write()` fixes it.

Comment: More simply `file.seek(0, 1)`

Comment: Similar recent issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78176770/235698.  It's documented in C `fopen` but I haven't found where Python mentions it (if at all).

Comment: @MarkTolonen It's at the end of section 7.2.1 - [methods of file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), and possibly elsewhere.  I quoted the relevant text in a comment on one of the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `seek` call between reading and writing:

```
import os
with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
    file.read(3)
    file.seek(0, os.SEEK_CUR)
    file.write("friend!")
```

Unfortunately, I don't think Python documents this anywhere. C [documents](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7) a similar requirement, but I think Python's requirement is just completely undocumented.

Note that with variable-width text encodings, trying to write N characters into the middle of a file isn't guaranteed to overwrite N existing characters. If you're not careful, you can easily end up overwriting half a character and corrupting your file.

Comment: Thanks! What I am hearing is that to be safe, use the file.seek(3,0), which is what I did in my first code snippet. So it seems to be an issue with reading followed by writing. I am still not fully satisfied with the explanation, other than that it is an undocumented behavior. (not a knock on your thoughtful answer since you didn't design the language and are just the messenger). Thanks!

Comment: So it seems that `.tell()` returns you the current stream position, but it isn't necessarily synchronized, hence calling `seek(0,os.SEEK_CUR)` will synchronize the stream position?

Comment: This is documented in Chapter 7 of the documentation under [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) `In text files (those opened without a b in the mode string), only seeks relative to the beginning of the file are allowed (the exception being seeking to the very file end with seek(0, 2)) and the only valid offset values are those returned from the f.tell(), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour.`

Comment: Sorry, a more accurate link would be [7.2.1 - Methods of file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: @nigh_anxiety So that indicates only `file.seek(file.tell())` is valid on a text file and implies `file.seek(os.SEEK_CUR)` would be undefined behavior, but still doesn’t clarify that it’s needed when switching from reads to writes or vice versa.

Comment: The fact that in text mode only seeks relative to the beginning of the file are allowed (i.e. whence = 0)  is not related to the issue in the original question, which is more about switching between reading and writing and the fact that on one hand file.tell() reveals your file pointer at a certain place, but .write() writes at the end of the file which is baffling and unexpected. The solution seems to be to use seek(0,1) to "sync" the pointer before writing. This part, as far as I have seen is not documented.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the file in the default "text" mode, by not providing a "b" specifier for binary mode, like in `open(file, "rb+")`. The text mode is the default one (one could also use the "t" specifier, as in `open(file, "rt+")`), meaning that underneath all file I/O is text oriented, and reads will do buffered I/O underneath.

So, despite the `.tell` method telling you a cursor position, from where a read would continue, the O.S. level file pointer is at the end of the file and writing resumes from there.

Yes, it is a plain incorrect behavior, but that is because file-exact position with "seek" and writing at the middle of the file has never been expected to work with files open in the "text" mode - for the single reason the most visible change in this mode is a translation of line-endings (on Windows, where the sequence `\r\n` - 2 bytes, is translated to a single `\n` character in a seamless way). So, file positioning in text files is not regarded as deterministic (and the extra buffering for read you had hit, insure it indeed is not).

So, the "workaround" for your issue is just to work with the files in binary mode, as it is the only mode that is actually expected to work with positioning and read/writing bytes at precise positions in the file:

```
In [51]: filename = "file.txt"

In [52]: open(filename, "wb").write(b"hi world!")
Out[52]: 9


In [54]: # original file has "hi world!"
    ...: with open(filename, 'rb+') as file:
    ...:     file.read(3) # We read characters at index 0,1,2 and move t
    ...: he file pointer to index 3
    ...:     print(file.tell()) # prints 3
    ...:     file.write(b"friend!")
    ...: # file now has "hi world!friend!"
    ...: 
3

In [55]: open(filename).read()
Out[55]: 'hi friend!'
```

(also note you must write a bytes-object (with the "b" prefix) not text to a file open in binary mode)

Comment: Wow! This is very interesting behavior. I commend you on finding this answer. Thanks!