# Deleting contents of file after a specific line in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file in this format :

```
22||512|6682,4865,4866,49200,52393,52392,49171,53,10|354,0,16,5,13,18,51,45,43,27,10794,21|14906
22,20||122,1|4865|51,43|29
|23|2064|||
20|23|1,53|||
|23|87|||
|23|322|||
|23,23|445,66|||
|23|26|||
```

I want to remove all lines that are below the line "20|23|1,53|||"
I didn't figure out how to do this in python

Comment: Read from the file, and write lines until you get to that line. If you want this to be robust (no data loss), you should do this with a separate input and output file, then use `mv` to atomically overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using truncate as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858088/truncating-a-text-file-does-not-change-the-file)

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as file:
  line = file.readline()
  while line:
      if line.rstrip() == '20|23|1,53|||':
          file.truncate(file.tell()) # tell returns current position of file read/write pointer
          break
      line = file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text=""
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write( text[ : text.find("20|23|1,53|||") ] )
```

first, we read the content of file.txt and move it into the variable text.
Then, we use text.find to find where the string "20|23|1,53|||" is located (it will return the index of where it is)
Finally, we overwrite the content of file.txt with everything that is in the text variable except the "20|23|1,53|||" (and what is after).